# Data from database is not showing

Tags: php, mysql

How can I get data from my database to show. I am not very experienced with PHP or MySQL.

I do not get an error message but no data shows so what am I doing wrong?

PHP

```
<?php
if(strlen(trim($_POST['search'])) > 0) {

$search = "%" . $_POST["search"] . "%";
$searchterm = "%" . $_POST["searchterm"] . "%";

mysql_connect ("cust-mysql-123-03", "", "");
mysql_select_db ("weezycouk_641290_db1");
if (!empty($_POST["search_string"])) 
{ 

}  

$query = "SELECT name,lastname,email FROM contact WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' AND 
lastname      LIKE '%$searchterm%'";

$result = mysql_query ($query);
echo mysql_error();
if ($result) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo $row["name"];
echo $row["lastname"];
echo $row["email"];
} ?>


<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>
<br>
<?php echo $row["lastname"]; ?>
<br>
<?php echo $row["email"]; ?>


<?php
}
}
?>
```

Comment: echo mysql_error(); after mysql_query()..

Comment: I updated my question php code with that and used it in my actual code but still nothing

Comment: @James Debug your code. Install a debugger or place variable dump statements throughout your code to trace its path. Verify each condition is met to your satisfaction and step forward. You're asking people to find a needle in a haystack when 5 minutes of simple debugging could fix this.

Comment: Text has finally appeared on the search results page. I have two search bars "name" and "last name" and when a name is entered the name and last name appear along with another bit of data "email." This now shows:


SELECT name,lastname,email FROM test_mysql WHERE name LIKE '%shannon%' AND lastname LIKE '%%'shannondoyle@gmail.com

Why is it showing like this?

Comment: You should update your question with the new code and this details.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
<?php
if(strlen(trim($_POST['search'])) > 0) {

mysql_connect ("cust-mysql-123-03", "", "");
mysql_select_db ("weezycouk_641290_db1");

$query = "SELECT name,lastname,email FROM contact WHERE name LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']) . "%' AND lastname LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['searchstring']) . "%'";

$result = mysql_query ($query);
echo mysql_error();
if ($result) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo $row["name"];
echo $row["lastname"];
echo $row["email"];
} ?>


<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>
<br>
<?php echo $row["lastname"]; ?>
<br>
<?php echo $row["email"]; ?>


<?php
}
}
?>
```

The mysql_real_escape_string is to prevent mysql injection which is a serious risk.

Comment: Thanks for the help but nothing changed! I really am not sure what is going on. there is no error message i corrected them and all the password, user, host is correct. why won't the data show on my results page?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the query you are executing returns record(s). You can check this by adding an echo statement which will print the query in your screen. Copy that and run it againist the database.You can use any mysql front end tools(php myadmin,mysqlyog to run the query. If there is any error in the query, you can see that then.

```
$query = "SELECT name,lastname,email FROM contact WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' AND 
lastname      LIKE '%$searchterm%'";
//the below line will print the query on the screen
echo $query;

$result = mysql_query ($query);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help but I included it and nothing happened?

Comment: add echo "Testing echo" before our new statement and see whether it prints "Testing echo" . Are you sure you are checking the same page where you changed ? Add echos in between the lines and see where it is breaking.